# Webcam not detected on Zenbook UX305FA

Tags: debian, camera, asus

I'm using Debian 10:

```
4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1 (2020-01-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Webcam worked ok before installing Discord and Zoom. After that it is not detected. 
It's sometimes seen in dmesg:

```
[11771.092506] usb 1-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[11771.227966] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=064e, idProduct=9700, bcdDevice= 1.01
[11771.227969] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[11771.227970] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam
[11771.227972] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: SuYin
[11771.227973] usb 1-1.5: SerialNumber: HF1019-T838-SN03-Rev0101
[11771.242710] input: USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam: USB2.0 UV as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/input/input45
[11774.291056] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[11774.742972] usb 1-1.3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
[11774.930987] usb 1-1.4: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[11777.577079] usb 1-1.5: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

I added this line to /etc/defaults/grub:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="usbcore.autosuspend=-1 quiet"
```

but no luck. Would be grateful for any advice.